# Trigger functions on anonymous signin and account linking on google identity authnetication

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-identity

I have rest services backend. I am using google identity platform to issue the token . There are some services which could be called anonymously, so I am using anonymous login in the identity platform. This returns a token , but I want to customize the claims in the returned token. With email-password authentication , I could trigger a google cloud function which would personalize the token. With anonymous authentication, the function is not being triggered.

Is there a way  to personalize the claims ?